# Looking for an alternative to a T-SQL Sub-Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
Account
=======
int AccountId PK

Order
=====
int OrderId PK
int AccountId FK
DateTime Date
int Status
```

For each account I want to know the most recent order that has a status of 1 (Success) otherwise the most recent order that has a status of 0 (Unsuccessful).  Date is not unique.

I've got this working with a correlated sub-query in a view like this...

```
SELECT
    a.AccountId,
    (SELECT TOP 1
            o.orderId
        FROM
            tbl_order o
        WHERE
            o.Accountid = a.AccountId
            AND
            o.Status IN (0, 1)
        ORDER BY
            o.Status DESC, o.Date DESC  
        ) AS OrderId
FROM
    tbl_account a
```

...but its slow.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query or the sub-query.  And it is a myth that correlated-subquery's are any slower than any other correct way of doing the same thing in any modern version of SQL Server (2000 and earlier do have this problem, however). The slowness here almost certainly is coming from poor/absent indexes or other causes.  If you supply your query plan and/or the table definitions including keys and indexes, we could help you better.

Comment: I think you might have a point. The view above runs seemingly instantly on its own but its slow when I join to it from another view. Its doing a 'nested loop - outer join. For each row in the top (outer) input, scan the bottom (inner) input, and output matching rows.' which doesn't sound too hot to me! :)

Comment: You're right @RBarryYoung - the sub-query works fine. So I've got view A and view B and B contains the query from my question. When A joins to B it runs slowly. When A and B run apart they run fine. The factor that makes the combination of the two run slowly appears to be a single join in the midsts of view A which is inside a derived table. Its a normal join that I've been able to move else where in A - outside of the derived table. So this is really strange and I'm not really capable at present of disciphering the change in execution plan which would have caused this...

Comment: If you post the Views, and the SQL Query, and the Table definitions along with their indexes, we might be able to help you.  Also, the query plan would be very helpful.

Comment: There's loads of it... maybe I will see if I can create a simplified query that demonstrates this odd slowness. Just to make it clear, moving the above mentioned simple join else where in the query got ride of the slowness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  a.AccountId, o.OrderId, o.Date, o.Status
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By a.AccountId ORDER BY o.Status DESC, o.Date DESC) 
    FROM Account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Order] o  ON a.AccountId = o.AccountId
)
SELECT AccountId, OrderId
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e1e3/4/0

Comment: Doesn't the OP's query act as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and return _all_ accounts?

Comment: @user92546: Yes, i think you're right. Edited my answer accordingly. Also changed the `ROW_NUMBER` to do a Partition By on AccountId since i assume that it's what OP needs.

Comment: Looks pretty cool @TimSchmelter. I think you've answered the question although it turned out that my sub-query wasn't by itself the cause of the slow down. I'd never heard of 'Partition'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.AccountId,
        o.OrderId
FROM
    tbl_account a OUTER APPLY 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 o.orderId
        FROM tbl_order o
       WHERE o.Accountid = a.AccountId
         AND o.Status IN (0, 1)
        ORDER BY o.Status DESC, o.Date DESC  
     ) AS o
```

Comment: OUTER APPLY to match the OP's implicit LEFT JOIN logic.